# How to know if Dropbox is in syncing using Dropbox API with Vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, api, dropbox

I need to get the Dropbox state (Syncing or Pause). I have installed Dropbox API in Visual Studio and I use VB.NET.
Thank you
Here my code:

```
Imports Dropbox.Api
Public Class Dropbox
    Private dbx As DropboxClient
    Public Property Oaut2AccessToken() As String
    Public Function DropboxIsSyncing() As Boolean
        dbx = New DropboxClient(Oaut2AccessToken)
        'HERE I NEED HELP...
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Please provide the code in your question.

Comment: You should be instantiating your `DropboxClient` in a task, not a function like that. This way you can wait for it to be completed, otherwise your UI can become unresponsive... On another note as far as I know, there is no call to determine if `Dropbox` is syncing in `vb.net`. There is although an API called [**Dropbox Sync API**](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/sync) that does this for mobile development.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're referring to the Dropbox desktop client, and want to know if it's currently uploading or downloading any files.

The Dropbox API doesn't currently offer a way to check the status of the official desktop client like that, but we'll consider it a feature request.